# What is difference between Console and Terminal in R?

Tags: terminal, console

I just need to ask that what is the exact difference between Console and terminal in R studio?

We can clearly see two options in bottom section where Console and Terminal are stacked together.

If both are same , then why R studio has mentioned them seperately?

[Console vs Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UWE7.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

In simple words: In console, you can run your R commands. In terminal, you can access your system shell.